# Regular expression help in PHP (8 hexadecimal characters followed by an underscore)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to validate if my input consists starting with 8 hexadecimal characters followed by a underscore, followed by any number of charters with any value.

Im currently using the following regular expression:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}_*/', $value);
```

But this expression does not fulfill my needs because it behaves the following way

Result:

```
1A345678            (true)
1A345678_add        (true)
1234567890          (true)
ABSDBASDB           (false)
```

Expected result:

```
1A345678            (false)
1A345678_add        (true)
1234567890          (false)
ABSDBASDB           (false)
```

What is wrong with my regular expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are just missing a `.`

```
preg_match('/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}_.*/', $value);
```

With `_*` you were matching for 0 or more underscores. `*` is a quantifier that repeats the preceding character or group 0 or more times. Therefor it matches also strings without the underscore at the end (0 repetitions of the _)

`.` is a regex special character, that matches any character (by default except newlines)

Comment: Yeah missed the quantitative interpetation of *. thanks for the answer!

Comment: Although technically this answer will do the trick, it's a little strange to include a match for characters you don't care about. .* is superfluous in this expression,and can (some say 'should') be omitted.  A match against '/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}_/' is concise and focused on the goal.  Or even better: '/^[0-9A-F]{8}_/i'

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the *:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}_/', $value);
```

Comment: This is the better answer.  It's kind of silly, actually, to include characters you don't care about in the match.  You only care about nine characters, so Limiting the match to those nine makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

replace * with .* after underscore

```
preg_match('/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}_.*/', $value);
```