# PHP extract 7 character Hexadecimal from text

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract 7 hexadecimal char from text.

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 1AA69C9 consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. 2de7890';

preg_match_all("/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{7}$/",$text,$result);
print_r($result);
```

Thank you.

[maybe similar to this but don't know why not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221420/regular-expression-help-in-php-8-hexadecimal-characters-followed-by-an-undersco)

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` from regexp string

Comment: Just keep in mind, that other regular words match that production, like `caffee` (I know, just 6 chars, but you get the point).

Comment: @Boldewyn: i see, btw the hexadecimal i need is always mixed. 
is it possible using regex? 
`/\b[0-9a-f]{7}\b/i`

Comment: @Andy yes, but it doesn't look so nice: `\b(?=[0-9A-Fa-f]*[0-9])[0-9A-Fa-f]{7}\b/`. It uses a [look-ahead assertation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) to make sure, there is at least one digit in the 7 chars. (Start → assert that any number of hex digits (`*`) and one digit follow → restrict to exactly length of exactly 7 hex digits.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^[0-9A-Fa-f]{7}$/` looks for hexadecimal string at the start and end of the string.

Remove `^` and `$` and make them word boundaries instead.

Use this:

```
/\b[0-9a-f]{7}\b/i
```

Comment: ...and replace them with `\b`, should be added.

Comment: i m accept this answer since my question related to hexadecimal. Niet explanation very usefull to me. Thank you both :)

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is requiring that the *entire string* consist of *only* those seven hex chars.

Remove the `^` and `$` to find the chars anywhere in the string, but beware that `abracadabra` would "match" as a six-digit hex "number" (`acadab`) so there may be other such false positives. Consider using this instead:

```
"/\b[0-9a-z]{7}\b/i"
```

This will avoid matching the middle of words.